# How to repeat string in freepascal

Tags: string, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

i need help with this problem that i have. I need to repeat a certain string multiple times. For example string 'hello' should be repeated 3 times with output like this:  hellohellohello

What I need to do is have user input an integer and after that another one(n). The program will repeat the first integer n-times. For example: 11 3:   111111

And that output should be integer ready to be compared to another integer.
So I tought that I have to input that as a integer, convert it to string, repeat the string n-times and put that new string to integer variable and than compare it to what I need to.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Another problem occured: apparently my code cannot use any uses. So how can it be done withou them?

Comment: So..., what do you have already ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, take [**The Tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a brief intro on Stack Overflow, and then read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question.

Comment: Re your EDIT, see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DupeString` function in the StrUtils unit for this:

```
program duplicatestring;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, StrUtils
  { you can add units after this };

begin
  writeln(DupeString('hello', 5));
  Readln;
end.
```

Obviously, I've hard-coded the string'hello' and 5 repeats in this example, but you could get the string and repeat count from user input or anywhere you like.  And you could write your own string function to generate N repeats of a given string by internally calling `DupeString`.

I suggest you look at `DupeString`'s souce code to see how this is implemented and then experiment with other methods of doing the same thing, e.g. using a `for`, `while` or `repeat untiil` loop.

Re your "no USES" update, the source code of `DupeString' shows one way to do this:

```
Function DupeString(const AText: string; ACount: Integer): string;
var i,l : SizeInt;
begin
 result:='';
 if aCount>=0 then
   begin
     l:=length(atext);
     SetLength(result,aCount*l);
     for i:=0 to ACount-1 do
       move(atext[1],Result[l*i+1],l);
   end;
end;
```

Basically, the `SetLength` allocates enough room on the heap for `ACount` copies of `AText`, then the `move` copies `AText` contents into the allocated space `ACount` times, and the function result tells its caller where to find the contents of the heap allocation (because of the H+ compiler directive - the result is returned differently if using H-, because that makes the compiler use old-style, length-byte-prefixed Pascal strings).

Another way is

```
function MyDupeString(const AText: string; ACount: Integer): string;
var i: SizeInt;
begin
 result:='';
 for i := 1 to ACount do
   Result := Result + AText;
end;
```

which is a lot less code, but a lot less efficient, because each iteration of the `for` loop causes a new heap allocation for the function result and a deallocation of the previous one.

And anything you can so with a Pascal `for` loop, you can do with a `while .. do` or `repeat until` one.  Challenge:  See if you can write your own `MyDupeString` which uses a `while` loop, and submit that as your answer to whoever has set you this task.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I managed to mutliply the string n times and then convert it to integer, ready to be compared to other integers. Thank you, first time using stack overflow and I am realy surprised how quickly I got help with a language like pascal.

Answer (score 1):

So the source code looks like this:

```
    program project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
   Classes, SysUtils, StrUtils
  { you can add units after this };
   var
    n,i:integer;
    dvojice:array[1..80,1..80] of integer;
    dvojicestr:array[1..80,1..80] of string;
    dvojicestr1:array[1..80,1..80] of string;
    dvojiceint:array[1..80,1..80] of integer;
begin
  readln (n);
  for i:=1 to n do begin
    read (dvojice[i,1],dvojice[i,2],dvojice[i,3],dvojice[i,4]);
    dvojicestr[i,1]:=inttostr(dvojice[i,1]);
    dvojicestr1[i,1]:=dupestring(dvojicestr[i,1],dvojice[i,2]);        
    dvojicestr[i,2]:=inttostr(dvojice[i,3]);
    dvojicestr1[i,2]:=dupestring(dvojicestr[i,2],dvojice[i,4]);
    dvojiceint[i,1]:=strtoint(dvojicestr1[i,1]);
    dvojiceint[i,2]:=strtoint(dvojicestr1[i,2]);
  end;
  writeln (dvojiceint[1,1]);                          
  writeln (dvojiceint[1,2]);
  writeln (dvojiceint[1,2]+dvojiceint[1,1]);
  readln;
  readln;
end.
```

I am sure that it can be more efficient, those arrays are so big just becouse i didnt't know how big I needed them. Names of the variables are in my native language, needed to do that for a teacher to read it. The last part is just for checking if it works correctly.

Comment: " those arrays are so big" I think your next step might be to learn about FPC `dynamic array`s - see http://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array.  These avoid you having to declare array structures with specific sizes *at all*.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely look into them. Didn't know that there is simething like that, I've beem coding for a year now so there is definitely much to improve.

Comment: Hey Dominik, did you actually post this as an extension of your question? If yes, you should have **edited your question** instead of writing an answer. Use the "edit" button under the **tags of your question** to activate the editor. Then again, I see you use the "dupestring" in your code, as suggested by @MartynA, so simply moving it to the question would make both your question and the answer look strange. To not mess up again, please remember that all information related to the question, MUST be in the question, and that the answer section is reserved for answers only. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, @TomBrunberg.  I was assuming that Dominik's answer was more in the nature of an "extended follow-up comment", which there really isn't AFAIK a good way to do, even without the restrictions on what a new user can do.

Comment: Yes @MartynA I agree with your assumption, as that would be normal in a discussion forum, f.ex. That is why I selected to give a "firm but neutral advice" instead of down votes, delete votes. You know ;).

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Indeed.  Personally, I think that the absence of "extended comment" support is a major factor in keeping up the quality of SO content and keeping down the noise - it's very noticeable when wading through the non-SO hits of googling how much more noise  - and just plain nonsense - they often contain.

Comment: @MartynA Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Ok, I just realized you suggested lookimg into dupestr source code , so I am gonna do just that.